How to categorize questions I follow
Apology if there's a really easy or widely known answer to this. But I've followed over 800 questions, and it's really a hassle to find the followed question I have in mind when I want to refresh my memory. Is it possible for me to put followed questions in different categories or lists? Thanks.

It sounds like you want to be saving questions, rather than following them.


It is possible to "Save" a question by clicking on the little icon below the downvote arrow which appears next to each question.  Saved items are automatically placed on a "For later" list of saved questions.


In your profile, there is a tab for "Saves".


Within that tab, there is an option to "Create new list".


Saved questions can be moved to your new list from within the "Saves" tab.



For more details, see the Meta announcement regarding "Saves".
